# Any way to enumerate class members?

Tags: php, member, enumerate

I have a class instance, and I want to enumerate its members.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php), or [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) if you are looking at an instance.

You could also use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's reflection API

```
$r = new ReflectionClass("domdocument");
foreach ($r->getProperties() as $name => $prop) { ... }
foreach ($r->getMethods() as $name => $method) { ... }
```